# Is there any way to click on disabled page using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate a scenario where I need to click on a disabled area to validate the next steps...

Could someone help me whether is it possible to click on the disabled page?

Regards,
Supriya.

Comment: If you're trying to click on a disabled element, and that element is ignoring your click, hasn't your test passed? Because it's disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JavaScriptExecutor`, because `WebDriver` is not able to click on elements which are `disabled` or invisible. So you can try something like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"your selector\").click()");
```

More information about `querySelector` you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Hi I am not understanding how to pass parameter to querySelector can you please  explain me in detail or any website so that i can make use of it properly.I used above code as:                                            
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#Wistia_container").click()");

Comment: I have in answer a link to querySelector. Also you have a typo in `querySelector(\"#Wistia_container")` - should be `querySelector(\"#Wistia_container\")`

Comment: Thank you Andrei..! let me try it once again...if it still doesn't work ll get back to you!